# Running IIS8 local server not working

Tags: windows-7, iis-8

I have a windows 7 laptop and I want to set up IIS8, php, mysql to run in a development environment, but I am having trouble.

I opened IIS8, and when I click on my site "Default website" and click start, it gives an error saying "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020)

Does anyone know whats going on?

Thanks

Comment: Something is using port 80. Are you running Skype?

Comment: I am, but how can I tell that it is skype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skype is hogging port 80 and 443 by default.

To block Skype from using them, go:

- Tools > Advanced > Connection
- Uncheck "Use port 80 and 443 for additional connections"

I've had to do this many, many times.